# How to change the format of datetime in en-US to en-IND (indian time) in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

heres my code...

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    orders.Status = "Billing Done";
    DateTime date= DateTime.ParseExact(salesmodel.Date.ToString(),                   
    "dd/MM/yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var sales = new Sale
    {
        OrderId = salesmodel.OrderId,
        Date=date,
        Amount = salesmodel.Amount,
        Freight = salesmodel.Freight,
        VatTypeId = salesmodel.VatTypeId,
        VatAmount=salesmodel.VatAmount,
        TotalAmount = salesmodel.TotalAmount,
        IsActive=salesmodel.IsActive,
        Status=salesmodel.Status
    };
    context.Sales.Add(sales);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return View();
```

its a controller action method.. I need to convert the format the datetime to Indian format of dd/MM/yyyy format but  my code is not working.

Comment: Do you get any result from `DateTime.ParseExact()`?  What is the input value in `salesmodel.Date`?

Comment: the input value is in the format MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.I need to show the date in indian format in my sales invoice

Comment: Are you aware of this mistake : `"dd/MM/yyy"` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
salesmodel.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```